# bitbucket authentication failed on Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to jenkins. I have a testing projects on bitbucket, shared with other collegues.

> 'https://***@bitbucket.org/*****/api_refactoring_automation.git/'

I tried to connect it to jenkins on my localhost and it works perfectly.

But when i use tha same configuration on another address (my collegue's ip address), it return me this error  :

> fatal: Authentication failed for
>   'https://***@bitbucket.org/*****/api_refactoring_automation.git/'.

This happens only in the pipeline console, because in the project's settings , when i insert the git url and the credentials, it works fine.

This is the console message:

```
> Started by user Marco Pagano
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://****@bitbucket.org/******/api_refactoring_automation.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/api_refactoring_automation
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Postman tests)
[Pipeline] git
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://****@bitbucket.org/******/api_refactoring_automation.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://****@bitbucket.org/******/api_refactoring_automation.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://****@bitbucket.org/******/api_refactoring_automation.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://****@bitbucket.org/******/api_refactoring_automation.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:888)
    ...
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://***@bitbucket.org/*******/api_refactoring_automation.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://****@bitbucket.org/*****/api_refactoring_automation.git/'
```

and this is my Jenkisfile:

```
 node {
         stage('Postman tests') {
          git 'https://marcopagano@bitbucket.org/mguillermaz/api_refactoring_automation.git'

             bat 'npm install'
             try{
                   bat 'npm run api_Luoghi/Comuni'
                 currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
            } catch(Exception ex){
                  currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE' 
           }

          junit 'newman_comuni.xml'

          try{
                bat 'npm run api_Luoghi/Province'
                  currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
            } catch(Exception ex){
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE' 
              }

              junit 'newman_province.xml' 

        try{
                     bat 'npm run api_Luoghi/Stati'
               currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
             } catch(Exception ex){
       currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE' 
             }
          junit 'newman_stati.xml'

                 try{
                bat 'npm run api_Carte_di_credito'
              currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
            } catch(Exception ex){
       currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE' 
              }
            junit 'newman_cartedicredito.xml'

             }
       }
```

I repeat, the configuration is exactly the same of the one on my localhost, but that one works. This is the console on this other one:

```
> Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://****@bitbucket.org/*****/api_refactoring_automation.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\api_refactoring_automation
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Postman tests)
[Pipeline] git
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://****@bitbucket.org/*****/api_refactoring_automation.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://****@bitbucket.org/*****/api_refactoring_automation.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://****@bitbucket.org/*****/api_refactoring_automation.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 0ec720b69aeb07834f916e91566e27d73fe2f6f6 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 0ec720b69aeb07834f916e91566e27d73fe2f6f6
 > git.exe branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git.exe branch -D master # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -b master 0ec720b69aeb07834f916e91566e27d73fe2f6f6
Commit message: "test suite modified"
 > git.exe rev-list --no-walk 5a2aff1eb97d6a796206c498bfa5728fa5ede11c # timeout=10
> [Pipeline] bat [api_refactoring_automation] Running batch script
> 
> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\api_refactoring_automation>npm install  npm
> WARN api_refactoring_automation@1.0.0 No repository field. npm WARN
> api_refactoring_automation@1.0.0 No license field. etc.
```

Comment: Did you try the ssh authentication? It should work better.

Comment: i didn't try it yet, but i don't understand why it should work on my localhost jenkins and not on the other. it's something i don't understand

Comment: Did you register the login/pwd as Jenkins credentials?

Comment: You mean in the pipeline settings? In that section Jenkis can connect with bitbucket. Infact it can read the Jenkinsfile which is in the repository. It is not able to connect when the pipeline starts, the third row of the Jenkinsfile

Comment: In Jenkins, you can define some secrets to store some login/pwd or secret text. Here one other solution to store the credentials for a https git clone: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html